# Angular $parse not returning locals

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to make an element draggable using jQuery and Angular directives:

```
function dragElement($parse) {
return {
  restrict: 'A',
  link: function($scope, ele, $attr) {
    var onDragStart = $attr.onDragStart ? $parse($attr.onDragStart) : null;
    var dragData = $scope.$eval($attr.dragData) || ele;
    ele.draggable({
      containment: 'document',
      revert: true,
      helper: "clone"
    });

    ele.on("dragstart", handleDragStart);

    function handleDragStart(e) {
      if (onDragStart) {
        $scope.$apply(function() {
          var locals = {
            $event: e,
            $dragData: dragData,
          };
          onDragStart($scope, locals); //locals are defined fine here
        });
      }
    }
  }
};
```

}

And in my controller, I have a function which is invoked when i start dragging. The function is getting invoked correctly, but the issue is that the arguments list is empty and my locals parsed in the directive are not available.

Controller Function

```
function handleFeatureDragStart($event, data) {
  console.log(arguments); //Empty
  console.log('inside handle feature start');
  console.log($event); //undefined
  console.log(data);//undefined
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't see, where you fire your handleFeatureDragStart function.

If 'onDragStart' is the function you want, you passing the arguments in a wrong way and use them incorrectly.

```
handleFeatureDragStart(e, data);

function handleFeatureDragStart(e, data) {}
```

'arguments' is empty, because you don't pass additional parameters.